# Type XXX is not assignable to type 'T' when using generic in typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a static function that can be referenced in the child classes. An example of `BaseClass` is as below

```
export abstract class BaseEntity {
    public static of<T>(params: Partial<T>, type: new () => T): T {
        const item = new type();

        Object.assign(type, params);

        return item;
    }
}
```

then I extended the BaseEntity with User class like below

```
export class User extends BaseEntity{
    public static of(params: Partial<User>): User {
        return super.of<User>(params, User);
    }
}
```

It seems like a legit code for me as I am providing User as the generic type and I have explicitly coded that the BaseEntity static function should return that of same type (which throws no error). However, writing this code produces below error

> TS2417: Class static side 'typeof User' incorrectly extends base class
> static side 'typeof BaseEntity'.    The types returned by 'of(...)'
> are incompatible between these types.Type 'User' is not assignable to
> type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could
> be unrelated to 'User'.

It seems to be saying that type User cannot be returned as the returned type T from parent class is not compatible with User type. It makes no sense to me whatsoever because I am explicitly providing to the generic type that T should be User. What am I doing wrong and how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. Are you trying to override static methods here? That's not gonna work, I'm afraid. ;) Static methods are bound to a class' constructor instead of its prototype. You can only call them on the class itself, not on an instance of a class. So your `BaseEntity.of()` method and `User.of()` method are actually two completely unrelated functions.

Your `BaseEntity.of()` method seems to be a factory method for your entities. Perhaps you can consider to use the `BaseEntity.of()` method and drop the `User.of()` method. The sample code below only creates only the static `of()` method in the `BaseEntity` class and uses it for initializing two `User` variables. (For demonstration purposes, I also added a `name` property to the `User` class.)

Some additional remarks though:

- It might be useful to swap the parameters of the `of()` function: first the `type` parameter (which should always be supplied), and second the `params` parameter (which could be optional in case you'd want to create a default instance).
- I noticed that in your `BaseEntity.of()` method you assign the contents of the `params` object to `type`, but I assume you want to assign them to `item` instead.

`BaseEntity.ts`:

```ts
export abstract class BaseEntity {
  static of<T extends BaseEntity>(type: new () => T, params?: Partial<T>) {
    const item = new type();
    Object.assign(item, params);
    return item;
  }

  //...
}
```

`User.ts`:

```ts
import { BaseEntity } from 'BaseEntity';

export class User extends BaseEntity {
  name?: string;
}
```

`main.ts`:

```ts
import { BaseEntity } from 'BaseEntity';
import { User } from 'User';

const user1 = BaseEntity.of(User, { name: 'John Doe' });
const user2 = BaseEntity.of(User);

console.log(user1.name); // John Doe
console.log(user2.name); // undefined
```

I assume that your `BaseEntity` class contains additional (base entity related) logic. But if that's not the case, you might want to extract the entity creation logic from the `BaseEntity` class and put it in a "global" factory function instead. When doing so, you can drop the `BaseEntity` class completely. As a result, your concrete entity classes will have one less dependency.

`createEntity.ts`:

```ts
export function createEntity<T>(type: new() => T, params?: Partial<T>) {
  const item = new type();
  Object.assign(item, params);
  return item;
}
```

`User.ts`:

```ts
export class User {
  name?: string;
}
```

`main.ts`:

```ts
import { createEntity } from 'createEntity';
import { User } from 'User';

const user1 = createEntity(User, { name: 'John Doe' });
const user2 = createEntity(User);

console.log(user1.name); // John Doe
console.log(user2.name); // undefined
```

Comment: perfect. just what I'm looking for.